# Do you understand what is written in this paper?

Tags: translation, kanji, handwriting

I can't recognize any of the characters, can somebody read it?

[image]

Comment: Not really a problem of unknown characters so much as bad handwriting. Really, they could have been more considerate on the non-native speaker and write more precisely. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Edited to incorporate information from comments]

> ６５４号室
>
> ビラルデイ
>   ホセルイス様
>
> 郵便物をセンタオフィス
>   にあずけています
>
> お受取り下さい
>
> 尼北局
>   （堀田）

So they're telling you to pick up your mail (or parcel?) at the センタオフィス (Center Office?)

---

Room #654
Mr. Berardi(?) José Luis

We have left/entrusted the mail/parcel for you at the Center Office.
Please pick it up.

Amagasaki-Kita Post Office
(Hotta)*
<sub>* Name of the deliverer</sub>

Comment: The name is ビラルデル・ホセ・ ルイス OMG I though learning hundreds of kanji and all the hiragana and katakana would help to go to japan T.T

Comment: 三つとも「ル」だったのねー読めないわｗｗ

Comment: Sorry is ビラルデイ jajaja

Comment: あ～　２個目は「イ」ね！ ww

Comment: 尼北局　which is the short form of 尼崎北郵便局

Comment: ^ 省略形だったのねｗ Oh, so you're in Amagasaki in Hyogo right now @LuisFernandoBadelMéndez A typhoon is approaching, it's pouring here in Kyoto! Stay safe :)

Comment: @Chocolate-san, (sorry but my workplace computer doesn't support Japanese writing), would you say that it's a notably bad handwriting? I have seen a few handwritings, and I could read pretty much all of them, even with kanji shortcuts, but that one... ew. I hope it's not usual...

Comment: @Rightleg: I would call it bad handwriting, but wouldn't go so far as calling it "notably" or "particularly" bad, although I find this particular person's katakana harder to read than most. The hiragana and kanji are pretty much within the range I'm used to seeing, though.

Comment: @Rightleg そうですよね、かなり汚いほうだと思います・・・宅配業者や郵便屋さんの不在連絡票って、字が汚いことが多い気がします。。机とか使わないで、屋外で急いで書いてるからかな―？とも思いますが。。。でも、もっと汚くて、ほぼ解読不能な字を書く人もたまにいます・・・